# Overriding methods with different variable names

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am having a methods like
// Base Class

```
public void foo(long A, long b,long c)
 {
    //Implementation 1
 }

//Derived Class

public void foo(long AA,long b,long c)
  {
   //Implementation 2
  }
```

I would like to what is wrong with this design ?
FYI:
I am using Proxy pattern for my design

Thanks

Comment: Have you changed the question adding the `Derived Class` comment ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The name of the parameters doesn't matter. Come run-time there is no way for java to tell which method you wanted to call at a given time. To overload methods the signatures have to be different so either there must be a different number of parameters or the parameters must be in a distinguishable order i.e. `String, int` and `int, String`.

Answer (score 3):

Overriding or overloading is based on types of variables but not on the variable names ( identifiers) itself. So, basically both of the methods have the same signature `void foo(long ,long ,long )`

Comment: No, Actually I am not overloading.There was no compiler error, Since I am overriding with  same method signature. I am asking whether if this is a bad design?  since I am having 2 Overridden methods with same arguments , but only the meaning of the arguments are different.Appreciate your inputs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going to add a sub class implementation for the foo() it is not bad. So, if you need a more specific implementation rather than going after general super class implementation, you must override it and add the specific implementation there as above.